# Concatenate string to integer in Ocaml

Tags: string, integer, ocaml, concatenation

I would like a working version of this:

```
let x = "a" ^ 0;;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you undoubtedly noticed, you can only concatenate strings with other strings - not integers. So you'll have to convert your integer to a string before you can concatenate it. If the integer is really hard coded like in your example, you can just write `"0"` instead of `0` (in fact in your example you can just write `"a0"` and not concatenate anything at all).

If the integer is not a constant, you can use `string_of_int` to convert it to a string. So this will work:

```
let x = "a" ^ string_of_int my_integer
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the usual printf functions but it is much [slower](http://www.lexifi.com/blog/note-about-performance-printf-and-format):

```
let x = Printf.sprintf "a%d" my_integer
```

Comment: Since there is no reason to assume that the string part is less variable than the integer part, I would have suggested `Printf.sprintf  "%s%d" "a" 0`.